Facebook Marketplace Page Doesn't Load Dynamically in Automated Browser (Using Splinter & Selenium)
I'm trying to automate browsing on Facebook's Marketplace using Splinter and Selenium. However, I've encountered an issue where Facebook refuses to dynamically load more results when I scroll down the page, even though I’ve written a script that should simulate the scrolling behavior.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

try:
    # Set up Chrome options to modify the user-agent and maximize the window
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Maximize the window
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")  # Custom user-agent
    
    # Initialize the browser with the modified options
    browser = Browser('chrome', headless=False, executable_path="C:\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
    
    # Facebook login page
    login_url = "https://www.facebook.com/login"
    browser.visit(login_url)

    # Enter login credentials
    WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email"))
    ).send_keys("your_email")  # Replace with your Facebook email

    WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pass"))
    ).send_keys("your_password")  # Replace with your Facebook password

    # Click the login button
    WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login"))
    ).click()

    # Wait for redirection to the marketplace
    time.sleep(5)

    # Visit the Facebook Marketplace page
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/orlando/search?daysSinceListed=1&sortBy=creation_time_descend&query=iphone%2013&exact=false"
    browser.visit(url)

    # Close any pop-ups if they appear
    try:
        close_button = WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Cerrar"]'))
        )
        close_button.click()
    except Exception:
        print("No pop-up to close.")

    # Scroll down the page to load more items
    scroll_count = 4
    scroll_delay = 2
    for _ in range(scroll_count):
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(scroll_delay)

    # Parsing the page content
    html = browser.html
    html_soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Find all product elements
    product_elements = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="x9f619 x78zum5 x1r8uery xdt5ytf x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k x1e558r4 x150jy0e x1iorvi4 xjkvuk6 xnpuxes x291uyu x1uepa24")

    # Extract and print product titles, prices, and locations
    for product in product_elements:
        title_element = product.find('span', class_="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6")
        product_title = title_element.get_text(strip=True) if title_element else "Title not found"
        price_element = product.find('span', class_="x193iq5w xeuugli x13faqbe x1vvkbs x1xmvt09 x1lliihq x1s928wv xhkezso x1gmr53x x1cpjm7i x1fgarty x1943h6x xudqn12 x676frb x1lkfr7t x1lbecb7 x1s688f xzsf02u")
        product_price = price_element.get_text(strip=True) if price_element else "Price not listed"
        location_element = product.find('span', class_="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6 xlyipyv xuxw1ft x1j85h84")
        product_location = location_element.get_text(strip=True) if location_element else "Location not listed"

        # Print extracted information
        print(f"Title: {product_title}")
        print(f"Price: {product_price}")
        print(f"Location: {product_location}")
        print("-" * 50)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    browser.quit()

What I’ve tried:
I’ve tried maximizing the window and setting a custom user-agent string.
I’ve added a delay after scrolling to allow more results to load.
I've started the webbrowser and put it to sleep infinitely and scrolled down manually and it doesnt load dynamically.
Problem: Even though the script seems to run fine and scrolls down, Facebook Marketplace doesn’t dynamically load more items, and the page doesn’t seem to update with new products after scrolling.

Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So they will do things to stop you from doing it.

there's gotta be a way to get around it.
